# How to repeat code in Lua?

Tags: lua, repeat

This is my first written code, because i've just started, so i'm not sure if anything is indented correctly. But i want a way to be able to repeat the text, but i'm not sure how to do it.

```
 print("Hey there. I want to play a game.")
    print("Tell me your name")
    print("Type your name")
    name = io.read()
    print("Oh, what a nice name. I was gonna call my kid the same")
    print("Ok. So as you can see, there are no ligths here. It's all dark. You have three choices. Go west, go east, go north.")
    print("To go North, type 'n'. To go East, type 'e'. to go West, type 'w'.")
    repeat
    direction = io.read() 
if direction == "w" then
    print(" You see a light switch.")
    print(" type 'switch'to turn on the switch.")
    print(" type 'go_back' to turn around")

    best = io.read() -- This is where i want it to be able to repeat
    end
    if best == "switch" then
            print(" The light goes on.")
                print(" As the light glows stronger, you see someone standing infront of you")
                print("Before you know it, he slits your throat. Want to try again?")
                print("Press enter to try again")
                try_again = io.read()
    best = io.read()


        direction = io.read()

elseif best == "switch" then
        print(" The light goes on.")
                print(" As the light glows stronger, you see someone standing infront of you")
                print("Before you know it, he slits your throat. Want to try again?")
                print("Press enter to try again")
                try_again = io.read()
                end
                end
                until best ~= "go_back" -- to repeat the code up above
```

Comment: type `how to repeat code in lua` into google

Comment: If you indent your code correctly it would show there's an extra `end` before `until`. About repeating code, enclose the strings you want to repeat into a function and call them as needed. Search for "multine strings" in Lua, it can be handy.

Answer (score 1):

To execute a chunk of code multiple times you can use so called control structures.

`while` exp `do` block `end`

`repeat` block `until` exp

`for` exp `do` block `end`

or the `goto` label statement.

Please read the reference for how to use them.
http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.4

You can either put your code block into one of those control statements or you can put it into a function which you then put into one of those control statements. Or you just call the function multiple times manually.

Code you intend to repeat is best placed into a function.

I suggest you do simple Lua tutorials and read both the Lua language reference Manual and Programming in Lua. Both can be found on www.lua.org

For indentation read http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaStyleGuide